# I can't find the activemq-core.jar in the $ACTIVEMQ_HOME/lib

Tags: activemq-classic

I can't find the activemq-core.jar in the $ACTIVEMQ_HOME/lib,the ActiveMQ version is 5.8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ActiveMQ 5.8.0 onwards there is no longer a activemq-core. 
The activemq-core has been split up into broker and client.
Instead there is a activemq-broker which is the broker JAR, and a activemq-client for the client JAR.